# Decorating item renderers in custom list components

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

Has anyone had success creating a custom list component which accepts a user defined item renderer, but decorates it with another class to augment its behavior?

Examples of why this might be useful include:

- catching and stopping the propagation of events or dispatching new events in place of others
- incorporating behavior in the renderer to interface with other packages used by the custom component
- adding expand and collapse buttons for resizing the internal renderer, etc

The idea here is to not require changing the users renderer to work with this component, so keep that in mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yep, I did this with the [Flextras DataSorter](https://www.flextras.com/index.cfm?event=ProductHome&productID=7).  The DataSorter is a customized list that acts like a Netflix Movie Queue.  The user's itemRenderer contains their stuff, but our wrapper adds in the number input field, the move up button, the move down button, and the other button controls.

It is pretty much a nightmare that required a lot of heavy customization of the Flex List class.

Since you're question is a "Yes" or "No" question, I feel I've answered it.  What else did you want to know?

Comment: I'm looking for insight that would save me from obnoxious List related pitfalls in this scenario (I think most already take a dim view of List extensibility).

Comment: The best insight I have to offer is don't try to do this, unless it is a last resort and you have exhausted all other options.  There are tons of "private" methods and non-accessible variables that will make you want to rip your hair out.  Monkey patching and/or creating your own list would almost be eaiser than extending the list class.

Comment: On the other hand, you may want to consider seeing if a dependency injenction framework, such as RobotLegs or Swiz will be able to do this for you "Automagically."  I don't know enough about how they work behind the scenes to tell, but it does seem plausible.